# Why does P2P need port forwarding when behind NAT?

Tags: network, ports, p2p

Correct me if I'm wrong, but for a node to participate in peer-to-peer, if it's behind NAT, it must port forward to be able to connect. Why is the port forwarding necessary? I know there are exceptions to this i.e. NAT traversals, but I'd like to understand the basic problem first. Can anyone explain in very simple terms?

Basically, my question is when and why is port forwarding necessary?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 main types of NAT, you can have one to one NAT (static NAT) where one internal IP address is translated to one external IP, and you have many to one NAT (hide NAT) where many IP addresses map to a single IP address. In many to one NAT when an internal host connects to an external host the IP information is put into session tables (I'm using this as a generic term to encompass all the tables a firewall may use in this case) so that the firewall knows what to do with return packets.

Things get a bit more complicated for sessions that are initiated by a host outside the firewall. With one to one NAT it's very simple as there's only one place the packet can go, but when there are many hosts behind a single IP address the routing device has no indicator of where an incoming packet should be directed. Port forwarding is one way to solve this problem, a port forward rule will allow the device to do the destination address translation and forward the packet accordingly.

Port translation is not often used as a solution in enterprise networks although I can think of some exceptions to that. Enterprises usually have a block of publicly routeable IPs, so they will set up a one to one NAT when an internal host requires access from an external IP (or just assign the box an external IP in the first place). Port translation is much more of a home broadband solution where your router only has one IP address to use. When you fire up your p2p software externally initiated connections won't be able to reach it unless it there's a port forwarding setup, either manually done but more likely UPnP, where the application tells the router what the port forwarding setup should be.

Comment: Is port translation a synonym for port forwarding?

Comment: Yes, port translation is what enables port forwarding to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a software, which is listening on a specified port. Basic problem is that you don't know what will be this port number after NAT traversal. It is important cause the remote software has to know this to be able to create a connection.

(More detail: You have to know this port after NAT traversal and send that to the remote client. What if that client also behind a NAT?)

Answer (score 1):

The common example of a P2P protocol is Bittorrent. In this protocol the communications are often managed by a tracker. This means for data transfer, a minimum of three nodes are needed:

```
+-----+               +---------+      +------+      
|     |  1.1.1.1:500  |         |      |      |      
| You |<------------->| Tracker |<---->| Peer |
|     |               |         |      |      |      
+-----+               +---------+      +------+
```

The connection for you starts with telling the tracker your IP address and port you are connectable on. The tracker then stores this in a state table:

```
+--------------+------------+
| Nodes        | Completion |
| 1.1.1.1:500  | 0%         |
| 2.2.2.2:1000 | 100%       |
+--------------+------------|
```

`Peer` has established he is connectible on port 1000. We'll come back to this.

Addresses `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2` represent the *external* addresses of NAT devices. These devices are ubiquitous in today's Internet since almost every user has a router installed to provide access to several computers, mobiles, games consoles etc..

This means that behind these addresses are more addresses, one for each of these devices.

However: since one address can only be connected to a port in the range `1-65535`, how does your router know whether to connect a request for port 500 to your computer with your torrent client running? You instruct it, by providing it with a rule called a port forward to say "any connections you receive on port 500, I want to be forwarded to me" - where `me` is your internal address (one of `10.x.x.x`, `192.168.x.x` or `172.16.x.x`).

As you have just joined the 'swarm' by announcing to the tracker, the tracker sends you the above state table. You know you have just joined and have 0% completion, but that `Peer` has 100% completion meaning you know if you connect to him you'll be able to start getting the data.

If `Peer` has not 'forwarded' his port (1000, as he reported to the tracker when he announced) however you will not be able to connect and start receiving data. This is obviously not desirable as now you cannot complete the torrent because no one is available to share it.

If `Peer` has not announced since you connected, he doesn't know you exist yet. However if you have set up port forwarding correctly, when he does announce and get the new state table with you in it, he could initiate the connection with you. This will work since your port is forwarded.

If **both** of you did not have port forwarding enabled, then despite the fact you were both announcing to the tracker, because the ports you told the tracker about don't actually reach back to your machine, all possible data connections are blocked by your routers/NAT devices.

So in brief: port forwarding **helps** with the health of P2P data exchange by making it easier for connections to be established - and unless every member enables port forwarding of some kind, it is impossible to exchange data in a P2P manner.